# Using aggrid export to csv feature, how to download data with column width set to max length of the data in a given column?

Tags: csv, export-to-csv, ag-grid

I am able to download data using export to csv file in aggrid but the downloaded file has fixed column width to all the columns. 
In free version, is it possible to change this or automatically set the column width based on the data length present in the grid?

`var excelParams = {
            onlySelected: rowsToExport(),
            columnKeys: ['A', 'B'],
            processCellCallback: formattingFunction,
            fileName: "Report.csv",
        };
gridOptions.api.exportDataAsCsv(excelParams);`

Note: rowsToExport() and formattingFunction are my custom functions and the above code works and downloads the data in csv

aggrid CSV Export:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-export/?framework=all#gsc.tab=0

Column Resizing(Only for the grid in UI):
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-resizing/?framework=all#gsc.tab=0

Comment: csv files don't have formatting. You would be better off using the `getDataAsCsv` function, then parsing the data into an xls file or using one of the various javascript tools that have been built for this purpose

Comment: I converted data received from getDataAsCsv function to JSon and using alasql, converted the file to xlsx. Still I'm not able to modify column width. Thanks anyway.